# Mac OS - PHP Fatal error Class 'Mongo' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I am working on a simple php script file. I need to connect to MongoDB to log something. But I am getting error with Mongo class

```
<?php
     $connection = new Mongo();
?>

Error:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mongo' not found
```

```
Application Versions
Mac 10.14.6 macOS Mojave
PHP 5.6.40

MongoDB shell version v5.0.1
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.1",
    "gitVersion": "*****",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

is there anything I am missing?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/#installation

Comment: @Phil I already followed these steps mentioned.

Comment: If you did, then you would have also seen that the connection class name is `MongoDB\Client`. You would also need to configure an autoloader or otherwise `include` the appropriate files into your script